# How to prove that f defines a function from F to S.

Tags: functions

Let $S$ be the set of all positive integers of the form $2^m3^n$, where $m > 0$,
$n > 0$, and let T be the set of all rational numbers. Define $f: S \to T$ by
$f(2^m 3^n ) = m/n$. Prove that $f$ defines a function from $S$ to $T$.

From the definition of a function, I have to prove that for every element of $S$, there is exactly one element of $T$. How do I prove it?

Comment: Not sure what it is you want to prove here.  Unique factorization tells you that no element in $S$ has more than one expression of the form $2^m3^n$...is that what you are after?

Comment: For instance, it would be different if, say, you looked at elements of the form $1^a2^b$.  There you'd have ambiguity since $1^12^2=1^22^2=1^32^2=\cdots$.  But unique factorization rules that out in your situation.

Comment: I agree with @lulu, you should be able to show that for any element of $T$ there is only one element of $S$

Comment: @Vasya  Unfortunately, that claim is not true.  $\frac 13\in T$ can come from $2^13^3$ or it can come from $2^23^6$, and so on.  The function is not injective.  But the OP was not asking for injectivity

Comment: @lulu: I guess it depends on the interpretation: if $T$ is the set of rationals, shouldn't  $1 \over 3$ and $2 \over 6$ represent the same element of $T$?

Comment: @Vasya  Yes, they are the same element of $T$, that's the point.  we have $f\left(2^13^3\right)=\frac 13=f\left(2^23^6\right)$.

Comment: I assume it means he needs to show it is well defined? If two such factorizations are equal then $m/n = m_1/n_1$.